# Webpack dev server don't reload page when rebuild file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm currently trying to put my webpack-dev-server on, but when I save my file and this been rebuild correctly my page dont't reload.

I use this script for ejecute:

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --host myIP --port 8080"` (Also I tried with `--hot --inline` and didn't work too)

Here is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const basedir = path.join(__dirname, '../');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        theme: path.join(basedir, 'assets/js', 'theme.js'),
        custom: path.join(basedir, 'assets/js', 'custom.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(basedir, 'assets/js'),
        filename: '[name]real.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And I import theme.js for example with:

`<script src='http://myIP:8080/themereal.js'></script>`

Comment: try to add `watch: true` to your webpack config. (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch#watch)

Comment: --watch as argument works too

Comment: Which version of webpack do you use ?

Comment: Watch didn't work!

Comment: @samb102 versions :     "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"

Comment: Could you try `webpack-dev-server --hotOnly` ? If it's not working, modify your webpack conf according to the documentation https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

Comment: I currently tried the --hotOnly, i will try hot-module-replacement

Comment: @samb102 What command should run with hot-module-replacement ? Webpack ?

Comment: If you did modify your conf with HMR, no extra arguments (like --hotOnly) is needed.

Comment: Answered for me, thank you to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried also with hot-module-replacement and it didn't work.

After search a lot I saw in the client console the following error:

```
Invalid Host/Origin header client:187:9
[WDS] Disconnected!
```

Then I search how to fix this and found `--disable-host-check` option, which works to me!

`"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --host myIP --port 8080 --disable-host-check"`

I hope this will be useful for somebody more!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the watch mode. Here is an example file i recently used.
You need not to set any more attributes in dev mode.

```
webpack --mode development
```

This config is webpack 4+

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    const {
        mode
    } = argv;
    return {
        module: {
            entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'app.js'),
            watch: mode !== 'production',
            output: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                filename: mode === 'production' ? 'bundle.min.js' : 'bundle.js'
            },
            rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
            }
            ],
            plugins: [
                new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                    title: 'App',
                    template: "./src/index.html",
                    filename: "./index.html"
                })
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried `--watch` and it didn't works too.. I currently resolve that, you can see my answer before!